# RxAndroid. Simple caching and filtering data

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I read a ton of literature about the Rx and, on the one hand, everything is clear, but on the other hand nothing is clear. I'm trying to do a simple filtration and storage of data from the server with this library, and it is not working as expected. I need to implement a simple channel list management:

```
1. Cache on disk and in memory
2. When user requested - return filtered channels
3. All Subscribers that was attached to this Observable must be notified if filtered cahnnels list was changed (call onNext() for all Subscribers)
```

I wrote the following:

```
ArrayList<Channel> channels = null;
ArrayList<Channel> filteredChannels = null;

Observable<ArrayList<Channel>> filteredObservable = Observable.create()
// here I need to check if cache is valid, if no - download from server
// then filter channels and return filteredChannels in onNext call
// all subscribers that called subscribe before and not called unsubscribe must be notified if filteredChannels changed
// how to implement this?
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

public void setFilter(Filter filter) {
// update filteredChannels with the new filter and notify all Subscribers (call onNext()). How to implement this?
}

public Observable<ArrayList<Channel>> getFilteredChannels() {
    return filteredObservable;
}
```

Do I correctly understood logic of the Rx pattern or not? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this task: I need to use `flatMap` and `map` and I tried to use `BehaviourSubject` to notify all subscribers for variable change, but this solution is not stable at all, because of error `MissingBackpressureException`, that's why I wrote next ObsevableValue class:

```
public class ObservableValue<T> {
    private static final String TAG = ObservableValue.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<Registration> subscriptions = new ArrayList<>();
    private T value;
    private int index;
    private boolean firstNotify;
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public ObservableValue() {
        firstNotify = false;
    }

    public ObservableValue(T defaultValue) {
        value = defaultValue;
        firstNotify = true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setValue(T value) {
        lock.lock();
        this.value = value;
        for (Registration listener: subscriptions) {
            if (!listener.isFinished()) {
                listener.getListener().valueChanged(value);
            }
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public T getValue() {
        lock.lock();
        T result = value;
        lock.unlock();
        return result;
    }

    public Registration subscribe(ValueChangeListener<T> listener) {
        lock.lock();
        Registration s = new Registration(this, index, listener);
        index++;
        subscriptions.add(s);
        if (firstNotify||value!=null) {
            listener.valueChanged(value);
        }
        lock.unlock();
        return s;
    }

    protected void finish(int index) {
        lock.lock();
        for (int i=0;i<subscriptions.size();i++) {
            Registration s = subscriptions.get(i);
            if (s.getIndex()==index) {
                subscriptions.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public abstract class ValueChangeListener<T> {
    private Looper looper;

    public ValueChangeListener() {}

    public ValueChangeListener(Looper looper) {
        this.looper = looper;
    }

    public void valueChanged(T data) {
        if (looper!=null) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(looper, msg -> {
                onValueChanged(data);
                return true;
            });
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        } else {
            onValueChanged(data);
        }
    }

    public abstract void onValueChanged(T data);
}

public class Registration {
    private ObservableValue observableValue;
    private int index;
    private ValueChangeListener listener;
    private volatile boolean finished = false;

    protected Registration(ObservableValue observableValue, int index, ValueChangeListener listener) {
        this.observableValue = observableValue;
        this.index = index;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    protected ValueChangeListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    protected int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finished;
    }

    public void finish() {
        finished = true;
        observableValue.finish(index);
    }
}
```

Now it is working as expected. Like in Rx ObservableValue returns a Registration object that need to be `finished()` when it is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.map()`'s function to filter your list and then return your desired output. This would mean that your Observable would be emitting the filtered results.

Then you could commit the filtered list to your cache in your `.subscribe()` functions.